# Cannot load or save configuration

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, webserver

I get this cannot load phpMyAdmin message. I've tried creating the config folder and the `config.inc.php` file. When I ĺog on to `localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/` it still gives me this message.

```
Error message: "Cannot load or save configuration Please create web server writable folder config in phpMyAdmin top level directory as described in documentation. Otherwise you will be only able to download or display it."
```

I have given the `www/html` folder full rights.

How to I fix this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: The error messages asks for a folder called "config" in the phpmyadmin top level directory. Apart from that "full rights" (I assume you mean 0777 by that) are never required for a web application and indeed open security issues. The folder has to be accessible and writable for the user account the http server uses to execute php scripts. That can be done best with group permissions.

Comment: as @arkascha writes, you need to create a dir /config/ wherever you put /phpmyadmin/ and also agreed, even for development and testing you don't need chmod 777. 755 will be all you need. If you've already done this, great. If you're learning about servers then take a few minutes to read up about access rights.

Comment: yes I've created the config folder and the config.inc.php. yes I used chmod 777. The error message still persists.

Comment: Im having exactly the same problem.  I wish someone would post a solution to this!

Comment: Any solution to this question? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issue on my Ubuntu 16.04. I made a research and in the end I found a resolution of the issue. Maybe my case solution will help somebody else.

Background: For security reasons I have non privileged user and group apache:apache (*`sudo groupadd apache | useradd -g apache apache`*). They are preset by directives (*`User apache; Group apache`*) in *`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`*. This user *`apache:apache`* owns Apache2 main directory (*`sudo chown -R apache:apache /etc/apache2`*) and some other files, for example: *`sudo chown -R apache:apache/etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup`*

In this manual: http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html - I found that...

> Debian and Ubuntu have changed way how setup is enabled and disabled,
>   in a way that single command has to be executed for either of these.
>
> To allow editing configuration invoke:
>
> `/usr/sbin/pma-configure`
>
> To block editing configuration invoke:
>
> `/usr/sbin/pma-secure`

**Note!** In the content of the two files listed above we talk about `/var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` instead of `/etc/phpmyadmin/config/config.inc.php`. **It was the key**.

In my case I was modified the content of these scripts (see below) and now I can use localhost/phpmyadmin/setup properly.

**/usr/sbin/pma-configure**:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Unsecuring phpMyAdmin installation..."
echo "Setup script can now write to the configuration file."
echo 
echo "Do not forget to run /usr/sbin/pma-secure after configuring,"
echo "otherwise your installation might be at risk of attack."

sudo sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
chmod 0660 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

**/usr/sbin/pma-secure:**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Securing phpMyAdmin installation..."
echo "Setup script won't be able to write configuration."

sudo sudo chown -R root:root /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
chmod 0640 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```